# MVVM Cross local:MvxBind is blank

Tags: xml, xamarin, textview, mvvmcross, android-databinding

**Important note: This used to work on MVVM Cross V3.5 but after upgrading to V6.4.2 it stopped working.**

In project which extensively uses MVVM Cross there is custom textview.

```
    <custom.HeaderTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marg_top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marg_top"
        android:gravity="center"
        local:MvxBind="Text SearchCriteria"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
```

The `local:MvxBind="Text SearchCriteria"` points to the view model which does indeed return text:

`public string SearchCriteria => Resource.SearchCriteria;`

And the string exists in resources:

```
    public static string SearchCriteria {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("SearchCriteria", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

For some reason it is always showing up on screen as blank when run. If I replace the textfield with a standard android one and use a standard assignment the text shows up.

`android:text="@string/test_string"`

So I know that the textfield is there, its on the screen and theres nothing blocking it, its just that textvalue is for some reason not getting set or not rendering (not sure which). Can you advise what the issue might be? If more information is needed please just ask. Thank you.

**Update**

I added breakpoint to the setter/getter for the binded value:

```
    public string SearchCriteria
    {
        get => searchCriteria; // Does not get called
        set => SetProperty(ref searchCriteria, value); // Is called with an actual value
    }
```

And only the setter fires (with a value) the getter never fires.

**Update** For further context, we tried setting the text directly on a button in the view using the ViewModel text getter and it works. So there is some sort of issue in the XML binding we don't understand.

```
Button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
Button.Text = ViewModel.SearchCriteria
```

We also made sure explicity bind the viewmodel and view:

```
ClaimsHistorySearchViewFragment_ : MvxFragment<ClaimsHistorySearchViewModel>
```

**Update** We found more issue with the view model. When we assigned a value to the ProptertyChange and explicity changed a value the PropertyChanged did not fire:

```
 public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            ViewModel.PropertyChanged += _model_PropertyChanged;
            ViewModel.ErrorCode = 0; // _model_PropertyChanged Does NOT fire
        }
```

**Note** The binding is working when we use fluent mvvm cross binding but not when we use localmvx binding

Comment: First of all, use `Textview` or  `EditText` to replace the `custom.HeaderTextView`, If you will meet same issue. Set the static value for `public string SearchCriteria =xxxx` directly, if it works.

Comment: It only appears if I replace the  `local:MvxBind="Text SearchCriteria"` with an `android:text="whatever". There seems to be an issue with the binding itself.

Comment: Have you checked that the DataContext of the control is the one you're trying to bind against? Don't you have binding errors on the output?

Comment: @fmaccaroni I can confirm the type is right and it compiles. Our view class sets the type explictly `public class ClaimsHistorySearchViewFragment_ : MvxFragment<ClaimsHistorySearchViewModel>,`. For further context, we have compared this views setup with other pages that are working (i.e. displaying text fine with binding) and our setup seems to be the exact same. And given that eplacing the binding line with straight text works we are very confused as to what aspect of debugging we are missing on this

Comment: @fmaccaroni And I can tell you this used to work on MVVM Cross v3.5 but after we upgraded to 6.4.2 it stopped working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a space in my import

`xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

Once I remove it, it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you are inheriting from `TextView` you can try registering the binding on your `Setup` > `FillTargetFactories` using the same [target binding](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Binding/Target/MvxTextViewTextTargetBinding.cs) that `TextView` uses:

```cs
registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<HeaderTextView>(
                "Text",
                textView => new MvxTextViewTextTargetBinding(textView));
```

HIH

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We just tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: @Aggressor One thing you can test is to set a converter that just returns the same value that it gets, so you can check if the binding is being fired.
Also I'd inherit from the `MvxTextViewTextTargetBinding` to make your own or copy paste its implementation, and debug in there what values are you getting or what could be happening

Comment: If we get the TextView by FindById and set its .Text value the text appears. However if we use bindings the setter is called but the getter is never called (the converter never fires either). I update my question with the setter/getter where only the setter is firing